# i signed a bond on 20 rs stamp before joining

Tags: contract-law, employment, india, labor-law

I am selected in one of the software companies, when i reached there to collect my offer letter, they told me to sign a bond on stamp paper(20 Rs).

The bond conditions are:

1. I will join company after one month.
2. I have to serve my service to company for at least one year after joining company.
3. If i am not able to serve service for one year and leave company before that i have to pay 1 lakh rupees to company.
4. I have to submit post dated check on 1 lakh rupees to company when i will join the company.

But now i have selected in another company with good offer, so i not want to join this company, So i told HR, but they are saying that they had started my joining process has i informed very late and said you had signed bond with us of 1 year, so you have to join our company.

So my concern is what possible legal action they can take against me or they cannot take any legal action on it.